# Is there any way in SQL Server 2005/2008 to reset a column to its default value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Some folks using our software have gone ahead and done a database server move not following our normal steps which accommodate the legacy portions of our software rending `nulls = 0` in all databases. So, since they ignored using our protocols, we're left with a lot of junk null data and a lot of queries for `fieldname = 0` that fail because `fieldname is null` is true instead.

So, how would one go about constructing a stored procedure to revert all nulls (there really should be no nulls) to the default value in a SQL Server database?

I have almost no experience doing stored procedures and absolutely no experience outside of Oracle DBs in stored procedures so please explain what the code is doing if you can answer this with a code sample and if it's impossible to run procedures over multiple tables, that's good to know too, in that case I'll just write a utility to do it (although I can already see that utility taking 9 years to run)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will list all of the nullable columns in your tables:

```
select tab.name, col.name 
from sys.columns col join sys.tables tab on col.object_id = tab.object_id
where tab.type = 'U' and col.is_nullable = 1
```

You could potentially use a cursor to loop through each, executing some dynamic SQL to update the column definitions.  But that could get quite nasty if you have different data types in each of the columns - are they all the same?

Alternatively, you could update all of your SP queries to use:

```
ISNULL(fieldname, 0) = 0
```

to eliminate the NULL problem from that side - this will match on NULL -or- Zero.

EDIT:

Ok, assuming you want to update all INT, TINYINT, BIGINT and BIT columns, this script ***should*** do it.  Use at your own risk though!  Backup the DB and restore it as a copy and test it on there.  Then, uncomment the table filter in the WHERE clause to test on a single table first.  The EXECs are commented, only uncomment once you've tested it to screen.

This script will do the following:

1. UPDATE every NULL INT, TINYINT, BIGINT and BIT to Zero (false)
2. ALTER every INT, TINYINT, BIGINT and BIT column to NOT NULL
3. ADD a default constraint to every INT, TINYINT, BIGINT and BIT column to Zero (false).

Note that 3 will fail if you already have a default constraint on the column.  Remove it if you do not need the default value (i.e. you are explicitly inserting a value for every INSERT).

```
DECLARE @table VARCHAR(MAX), @col VARCHAR(MAX), @type VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @q_update VARCHAR(MAX), @q_alter VARCHAR(MAX), @q_default VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE c CURSOR FOR

    select tab.name, col.name, typ.name
    from sys.columns col
          join sys.types typ on col.system_type_id = typ.system_type_id
          join sys.tables tab on col.object_id = tab.object_id

    where tab.type = 'U' and col.is_nullable = 1 and typ.name IN ('int', 'tinyint', 'bigint', 'bit')
    --tab.name = 'sometable'

OPEN c
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @table, @col, @type
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT 'UPDATING ' + @table + '.' + @col + ' (' + @type + ')';

    SET @q_update = 'UPDATE [' + @table + '] SET [' + @col + '] = 0 WHERE [' + @col + '] IS NULL';
    PRINT @q_update;
    --EXEC(@q_update);

    PRINT '';

    SET @q_alter = 'ALTER TABLE [' + @table + '] ALTER COLUMN [' + @col + '] ' + @type + ' NOT NULL';
    PRINT @q_alter;
    --EXEC(@q_alter);

    PRINT '';

    SET @q_default = 'ALTER TABLE [' + @table + '] ADD CONSTRAINT ' + @table + '_' + @col + '_DF DEFAULT 0 FOR [' + @col + ']'
    PRINT @q_default;
    --EXEC(@q_default);

    PRINT '----';

    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @table, @col, @type
END
CLOSE c
DEALLOCATE c
```

Note: I've used cursors for clarity.  Feel free to look at @JamesCurtis [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12748730/join-based-on-tables-that-vary-by-row/12748875#12748875) if you really don't want to use them.

Comment: It would just be on integers  and and small integers (the problem lies mainly with small integers used as boolean operators or some sort of enumerations)

Comment: rather than a cursor [use a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12748730/join-based-on-tables-that-vary-by-row/12748875#12748875), and the use of `DEFAULT` as mentioned by Steve will solve the data type problem

Comment: @JamesCurtis but is the answer to the OPs question that he must update the schema as well as the data?  Updating the NULLs to zeros doesn't eliminate any potential future INSERTs from being NULL.

Comment: @OffHeGoes thanks a lot for this script - now I've got to convince the guy handling the situation to actually use it (I'm just the programmer who overhears things and asks about them on stackoverflow) but I think this really helps.  One problem with our database schema is that we do have some non-zero constraints on integers.  I'm not sure how it happened, but these appear to have been ignored and lost when using some Microsoft conversion wizard, but those are few and far between and we can patch them up manually.

Comment: @PeterTurner Ok, well keep in mind that part 3 will fail if there are already default constraints on the columns.  And don't take the script at face value, make sure it works for your situation.

Answer (score 3):

Your title says set a field to null but your questions says there should be no nulls.  Nevertheless....you can use the DEFAULT keyword to set a field to it's default value:

```
Update MyTable set MyField = DEFAULT Where <something>
```

Comment: Thanks for reading my mind, I messed up that title.  That's easy enough and good to know about the DEFAULT keyword, but is it possible to iterate that query over all the fields in all the tables in a database?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a code sample that'll accomplish what you need.

**Massive disclaimer**.  This code will reset *every nullable column* that *has a default* back to its default.  You'll almost certainly want to limit its scope.

```
-- Routine which finds all NULLABLE columns with default values
-- and sets them back to their defaults.

-- DISCLAIMER.  If in any doubt, comment the EXEC out and copy and paste
-- the contents of @sql into a query window, and inspect before running.

-- Soon to hold executable SQL
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(Max)

-- Use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA to find all qualifying columns, building
-- up a string consisting of a series of simple update statements
--
-- Warning:  My definition of qualifying may differ from yours.
-- Check your WHERE clause. 
--
-- Doity concatenatin' ahoy, Captain!
SELECT
    @sql = 
    CASE WHEN
        @sql IS NULL
    THEN
        'UPDATE ' + TABLE_NAME + ' SET ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' = DEFAULT;'  
    ELSE 
        @sql + 'UPDATE ' + TABLE_NAME + ' SET ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' = DEFAULT;'   
    END
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
    COLUMN_DEFAULT IS NOT NULL
AND IS_NULLABLE = 'YES'
--  Add extra conditions for granularity!!!!

-- Execute sql
EXEC (@sql);
```